# NodeJs: child_process.stdout, `data` be cut off

Tags: node.js, process, child-process, javascript-automation

I am using NodeJs to run JXA (JavaScript for Automation). Below is my code:

```js
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const StringToStream = require('string-to-stream');

const code = `
ObjC.import('stdlib');
console.log('inited');
`;

const child = spawn(
    "osascript",
    ["-il", "JavaScript"],
    {
        maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024 * 1024
    }
);

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    // Very strange, it didn't run to here
});

child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
    // run to hear. but the data be cut off
});

StringToStream(`
console.log('... Very-Long-String ...');
`).pipe(child.stdin, { end: false })
```

Very strange, `stderr.on('data')` be fired, and `data` be cut off. It seems that the output stream is length limited.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?